# Expected string literal in condition express in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using `?:` to determine the build agent of Jenkins shared library groovy script like this:

```groovy
def call(String type, Map map) {
    if (type == "gradle") {
        pipeline {
            agent "${map.agent == null}" ? "any" : "${map.agent}"
        }
     }
}
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/jobs/soa-robot/builds/154/libs/pipeline-shared-library/vars/ci.groovy: 6: Expected string literal @ line 6, column 42.
    agent "${map.agent == null}" ? "any" : 
                                 ^

/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/jobs/soa-robot/builds/154/libs/pipeline-shared-library/vars/ci.groovy: 6: Only "agent none", "agent any" or "agent {...}" are allowed. @ line 6, column 13.
               agent "${map.agent == null}" ? "any" : "${map.agent}"
               ^

/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/jobs/soa-robot/builds/154/libs/pipeline-shared-library/vars/ci.groovy: 6: No agent type specified. Must be one of [any, docker, dockerfile, label, none] @ line 6, column 13.
               agent "${map.agent == null}" ? "any" : "${map.agent}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would start by figuring out what class the `agent` method lives in and take a look at the class or the javadoc to figure out what it is actually expecting as arguments. Took a quick look around but my jenkins-fu is too low. You could try something like `println(this)` or `println(delegate)` before the `agent` row (or however you log something in jenkins) to figure out what class the `agent` method lives in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is thrown by the pipeline syntax validator that runs before your pipeline code gets executed. The reason you see this error is the following:

```text
Only "agent none", "agent any" or "agent {...}" are allowed. @ line 6, column 13.
```

This is the constraint for the `label` section. It means that the following values are valid:

- `agent any`
- `agent none`
- `agent "constant string value here"`
- `agent { ... }`

When you pass something like:

- `agent "${map.agent ?: 'any'}`
- `agent(map.agent ?: 'any')`

you are getting `Expected string literal` because any form of an expression is not allowed in this place, including interpolated `GStrings` of any form.

#### Solution

There is a way to define pipeline agent dynamically however. All you have to do is to use a closure block with the `label` set to either expression or empty string ([an equivalent of `agent any` in this case](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43016?focusedCommentId=333915&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-333915).)

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        label map.agent ?: ''
    }

    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `label` section allows you to use any expression, so `map.agent` is a valid construction here. Just remember to use an empty string instead of `"any"` - otherwise Jenkins will search for a node labeled as "any".

Answer (score 2):

Don't use string replacments *everyhwhere*:

```
agent(map.agent==null ? "any" : map.agent)
```

Or get groovy:

```
agent(map.agent?:"any")
```

The actual problem is most likely the "ternary operator" battling against the "parens are maybe optional"-rule.

Comment: still this error: `/Users/dabaidabai/.jenkins/jobs/soa-robot/builds/156/libs/pipeline-shared-library/vars/ci.groovy: 6: Expected string literal @ line 6, column 19.
               agent(map.agent==null ? "any" : map.agent)` @cfrick

Comment: Reading the Jenkins pipeline docs you are supposed to use `agent any` where `any` is one of a set of allowed values. I.e. not `agent "any"`. Not sure what type it resolves to in Jenkins.

Comment: @Dolphin I'll keep this answer around, so people can see, that the most obvious problems where addressed. I'd tag this with the appropriate jenkins tag instead of groovy so people used to this kind of nonsese might be able to help out.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `agent` is a method taking a string argument and the way your code is written is ambiguous. Try surrounding the argument expression with parens:

```
agent(map.agent == null ? "any" : "${map.agent}")
```

I removed the quotes around `map.agent == null` as they seemed extraneous.

Also this could probably be rewritten using the groovy "elvis operator" (`:?`) as:

```
agent(map.agent ?: "any")
```

Which essentially means "use map.agent if it has a value, otherwise use 'any'". "If it has a value" is in this context being defined using groovy truth where both empty string and null represent "no value".

Comment: Was writing this on a phone. Took forever. This answer is essentially the same as cfricks.